# Adding a auto increment field to MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting this error:

**INSERT failed: INSERT INTO clientcontact VALUES('Don Jones', 'Walmart', 'need help', 'don@icsbranch.net', '772-991-0122')
Column count doesn't match value count at row 1**

I am trying to pass a NULL field from get_post function, which is an auto-increment ID field.  Just wondering what I need to change so that the user can fill out the form and have the info entered into the database with the inquiryID auto populated.

```
<?php 

require_once 'login.php';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

if (!$db_server) die("Unable to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database, $db_server)
or die("Unable to select database: " . mysql_error());

{
$name   = get_post('name');
$company   = get_post('company');
$description = get_post('description');
$email     = get_post('email');
$phone    = get_post('phone');
$inquiryID = get_post('inquiryID');


$query = "INSERT INTO clientcontact VALUES" .
    "('$name', '$company', '$description', '$email', '$phone', NULL)";

if (!mysql_query($query, $db_server))
    echo "INSERT failed: $query<br />" .
    mysql_error() . "<br /><br />";
}

echo <<<_END
<form action="index.php" method="post"><pre>
       Name: <input type="text" name="name" />
    Company: <input type="text" name="company" />
    Inquiry Details: <input type="text" name="description" />
     E-Mail: <input type="text" name="email" />
   Phone Number: <input type="text" name="phone" />
     <input type="submit" value="ADD RECORD" />

</pre></form>
_END;

mysql_close($db_server);

function get_post($var)
{
return mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}
?>
```

Comment: You really ought to use a columns list. `INSERT INTO clientcontact (name, company, description, email, phone, id) VALUES (...all your vars...)`  Will make it much easier to be sure you have not omitted a column because without the column list, you _must_ supply a value for every column in the correct order.

Comment: if id is auto_increment shouldn't you not insert value NULL. at least if its a key.

Comment: Do what Michael Berkowski suggested. And do not insert an id (no name, no value).

Answer (score 2):

Please do the following:

1. Cross check that there is a column og primary key with property Auto Increment.
2. for the insert query written please add column name before the VALUE keyword
   for eg:

   INSERT INTO TABLENAME (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3) VALUES (value1, value2, value3)

Just ignore the auto increment field in the column and value set. So the query for you will be

```
$query = "INSERT INTO clientcontact (name_column, company_column, desc_column, email_column, phone_cloumn) VALUES" .
    "('$name', '$company', '$description', '$email', '$phone')";
```

Please replace your column name in the above query and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO clientcontact VALUES" .
    "('$name', '$company', '$description', '$email', '$phone')";
```

(you don't pass the NULL)

But you should really use

```
$query = "INSERT INTO clientcontact VALUES (name, company, description, email, phone) VALUES ('$name', '$company', '$description', '$email', '$phone')";
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO clientcontact SET
   name = '" . $name . "',
   company = '" . $company . "',
   description = '" . $description . "',
   email = '" . $email . "',
   phone = " . $phone . ",
";
```